# Disabling master node from running as a slave node in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am running YARN in 3 nodes (1 master and two slaves). After running some applications, I realized that the master acts as a slave too.

How can I prevent this from happening? I need the master to act as a master only.

Comment: I think removing master machine name from /hadoop/etc/slaves will work

Comment: I removed it. It didn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to run Slave on Master, you need to remove Master IP or hostname from Slave file, after that refresh nodes.

If its post the result